# Input string was not in a correct format, MySQL Entity Framework Core

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I am getting errors when I try to send string parameters using EF Core in ASP.NET Core 5  and use EF MySQL 5.0.8. The error is Input string was not in a correct format.

I am using this EF Core Library:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

If I send int parameters the solution below works fine.

**MYSQL Procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`MYUSER`@`%` PROCEDURE `test_sp`(
    IN param1 int,
    IN param2 text
#I tried type text, varchar, char
)
BEGIN

        SELECT 1 as id, param1 as parameter, 'this is Parameter 1 INT' as text
        UNION
        SELECT 2 as id, param2 as parameter, 'this is Parameter 2 VARCHAR' as text;
        
END
```

**ASP.NET CORE 5 CLASS**

```
public async Task<List<T>> ExecuteStoredProcedure(string nameProcedure, List<MySqlParameter> parameters = null)
{
    try
    {
        using (var data = new ContextBase(_optionBuilder))
        {

            //Add Space to separate sp name of the parameters
            nameProcedure += "(";
            var count = parameters.Count;
            int i = 0;
            //Insert the parameters in the procedure name
            for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {

                nameProcedure += parameters[i].ParameterName;

                if(i + 1 < count)
                {
                    nameProcedure += ", ";
                }
                else
                {
                    nameProcedure += ")";
                }
            }

            //Remove the last Comma from the query
            var responseData = await data.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw<T>("CALL " + nameProcedure, parameters.ToArray()).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

            return responseData;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLog error = new ErrorLog();
        error.Error = ex.Message;
        error.Description = "Error encountered DB Procedure Execute ***. Message:" + ex.Message + " when getting the Generic Procedure Execute";
        error.Section = "RepositoryProcedureGenerics.cs";
        error.Layer = "Infra";
        error.Date = DateTime.Now;
        await this.CreateError(error);

        return null;
    }
}
```

**ASP.NET CORE CONTROLLER**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExecProcedure([FromQuery(Name = "param1")] int param1, [FromQuery(Name = "param2")] string param2)
{

    //Create the list of Parameters
    List<MySqlParameter> listParameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();

    //int par = 1;
    //string par2 = "XXX";

    listParameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@param1", MySqlDbType.Int32));
//I TRIED      MySqlDbType.Text, MySqlDbType.VarChar and MySqlDbType.VarString       
listParameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@param2", MySqlDbType.Text));

    listParameters[0].Value = param1;
    listParameters[1].Value = param2;


    string sp_name = "test_sp";


    //Execute the Procedures
    List<Test> test = await _procedureExecutor.ExecuteStoredProcedure(sp_name, listParameters.ToList());

    return Ok();
}
```

Does someone knows where is my mistake?